# VBS Reg error in Win7 32bit & 64bit

Tags: windows, excel, vbscript, dllregistration, vba

I have made the following script in VBS but although it does work in windows xp & vista, I cant get it to work in win7 both 32 & 64 bit.

```
set myclip = createobject("clipbrd.clipboard")
bcode = myclip.gettext
if len(bcode) > 0 then
set wb = getobject("C:\DB.xlsx")
wb.sheets("1").range("a2").value = bcode
myclip.clear
myclip.settext wb.sheets("1").range("c2")
set wb = nothing
end if
set myclip = nothing
```

Through elevated `cmd regsvr32` I get the

`Regsvr32 DllRegisterServer in clipboard.dll succeded`.

However when I try to run the vbs I get the following error:

`Line: 1 Char: 1 ActiveX component can't create object 'clipbrd.clipboard' Code: 800A01AD S`

Any ideas how to get passed it?

Comment: Are you registering it as a 32 or 64-bit ActiveX component? Are you using the 32 or 64-bit version of WScript?

Comment: I tried both but no success

Answer (score 0):

If it registered, but can't be instantiated there may be something it expects to be able to access during creation that it cannot access.  There is a comment where you got this from:
"Note the constants i copied from msdn may not all be correct, or are outdated, see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebwdx8yh.aspx"
Based on that I suspect that one of the constant he copied from msdn is no longer available in Windows 7, or has changed, and that because of that it throws an error during creation.
Just a guess, but worth checking if you have VBS source.